# C++ fails to extern "C"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-phone

So I'm making a Windows Phone native C++ DirectX app in Visual Studio and for no particular reason I'm getting errors from sal.h

I have no idea why should that happen, nor why is it complaining about `extern "C"`

It says

```
missing ";" before "string"
missing ";" before "{"
```

The full code for that part

```
#ifdef  __cplusplus // [
#ifndef __nothrow // [
# define __nothrow __declspec(nothrow)
#endif // ]
extern "C" { // errors are at this line
#else // ][
#ifndef __nothrow // [
# define __nothrow
#endif // ]
#endif  /* #ifdef __cplusplus */ // ]
```

So it's definitely being compiled with C++ compiler since `__cplusplus` is defined

Any ideas why in the world should that happen?

Comment: And where is end of extern parenthesis?

Comment: The end is way back down in the same sal.h; sal.h is Visual Studio provided header for something. The file is totally correct.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong either is sal.h before the section in your question, or in the file including sal.h before the include.

Comment: Ok, tried to find it. I don't even include this sal.h anywhere, and there are no other errors, so I'm completely confused about that.

Comment: You include sal.h indirectly. Show your source, since it is not likely that MS headers will contain errors - it is errors in your sources which cause the problem.

Comment: There's an error in one of your own files that confuses the parser. A common culprit is forgetting a semicolon after a class or struct definition.

Comment: @molbdino right, just a simple ";" I missed turned out to be the error somewhere else. Thanks for noticing! Such a stupid mistake though...

Comment: Not a stupid mistake at all, very common in fact. The trick is to know when the compiler spits out a million seemly bizarre errors that it's all because of something simple like this. Unbalanced preprocessor `ifdef`s are another great way to send the compiler into a tailspin.